# How to write a letter "M" on the central line in this simple code?

Tags: tkz-tab

With the code below, I'll get
[image]
But I want this output:
[image]
**How can I do that?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{t style/.style = {style = solid}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]
{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1 }%
{$v_1$ , $v_2$ , $v_3$ }%
\tkzTabLine{ z, , t , ,z }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how did you get the `0`'s?

Comment: @naphaneal: By typing `z`'s

Answer (score 5):

You can use the help option. With the macro `\tkzTabInit` and with the macro `\tkzTabInit`.
With the last one you see the name of the node: Z21 `\node at (Z21) {M};`is exactly what you want !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{t style/.style = {style = solid}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5,help]
{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1 }%
{$v_1$ , $v_2$ , $v_3$ }%
\tkzTabLine[help]{ z, , t , ,z }
% \node at (Z21) {M};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{t style/.style = {style = solid}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]
{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1 }%
{$v_1$ , $v_2$ , $v_3$ }%
\tkzTabLine{ z, , t , ,z }
 \node at (Z21) {M};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, maybe someone else will find something more refined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{t style/.style = {style = solid}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]
{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1 }%
{$v_1$ , $v_2$ , $v_3$ }%
\tkzTabLine{ z, , t , ,z }
\node at (4,-1.5) {M}; % I've simply defined a node in the right position
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't there an standard way like `t{M}` to do that really?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I haven't found anything on http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/downloads/TKZdoc-tab.pdf, I hope someone else will help you!